# How to configure mmenu to go directly to a submenu item

Tags: mmenu

Is it possible to expand to a specific submenu item upon clicking a link on a page?

http://mmenu.frebsite.nl

Answer (score 0):

In `mmenu.js` line 983 I changed:

```
var $menu = $(".menu-menu").clone()
```

Maybe not exactly what you want. This sets the root element of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the `li` of the link you want to default to, then initialize mmenu using the `classNames` and `selected` object configuration setting:

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
    //Options        
    "offCanvas": {
        "zposition": "front" //Just an example option
    }
}, {
    //Configuration
    classNames: {
        selected: "current-page" //Change this class to match the default li you want
    }
});
```